# queue in C array with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, queue

I have tried to implement queue by array and pointers in C language. The queue
is modeled by C structure

```
// Circular Buffer
typedef struct{
    main_controller_req_t     buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];   // buffer
    uint16_t                  size;                  // length of the queue
    uint16_t                  count;                 // number of elements present in the queue
    main_controller_req_t     *p_head;               // pointer to head of the queue (read end)
    main_controller_req_t     *p_tail;               // pointer to tail of the queue (write end)
}circular_buffer_t;
```

I have implemented function for queue initialization

```
void init_cb(circular_buffer_t *p_cb){

    p_cb->p_head = p_cb->buffer;
    p_cb->p_tail = p_cb->buffer;
    p_cb->count = 0;
    p_cb->size = BUFFER_SIZE;

}
```

and function for inserting onto the queue

```
BOOL enqueue_cb(circular_buffer_t *p_cb, main_controller_req_t *p_enq_elem){

    if(p_cb->count < p_cb->size){

        // queue contains at least one free element

        taskENTER_CRITICAL();

            // insert the element at the tail of queue
            *(p_cb->p_tail) = *p_enq_elem;
            // incrementing modulo size
            p_cb->p_tail = (((p_cb->p_tail++) == (p_cb->buffer + p_cb->size)) ? (p_cb->buffer) : (p_cb->p_tail));
            // one element added
            p_cb->count++;

        taskEXIT_CRITICAL();

        return TRUE;

    }else{

        // queue is full
        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

The enqueue_cb function works well until the tail reaches BUFFER_SIZE. Then the
program crashes and uC resets. The problem is in p_tail pointer update but I don't
understand why. Please can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you do all your libraries which are not dependant for CPU on your PC (Visual studio or similar). It will ease your debugging and will produce less questions.

Comment: Please provide a little portion of your main function where your usage leads to the crash.

Comment: @Steve> You cannot assign p_cb->p_tail **and** use `++` on it in the same statement. (well to be fair you can, you're just making your code difficult to understand, even by yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your test...  You check for overrun, but *before* incrementing the pointer, this causes  `p_cb->p_tail`to go past the end of your circular buffer.

```
 p_cb->p_tail = ((p_cb->p_tail++) == (p_cb->buffer + p_cb->size)) 
                    ? (p_cb->buffer) 
                    : (p_cb->p_tail);
```

You must test the value of tail *after* incrementing.

```
 p_cb->p_tail = (++(p_cb->p_tail) >= (p_cb->buffer + p_cb->size)) 
                    ? p_cb->buffer 
                    : p_cb->p_tail;
```

As an aside, a linked list is not a very efficient way of implementing a circular buffer.  Have you considered using a simple fifo buffer implementation?

The fifo construct is so common, that it's useful to have a **universal** macro implementation for C.  It is thread-safe (no locks needed) if you only have one producer and one consumer.

These macros are very easy to optimize by the compiler.

It's a good tool to have in one's toolbox.

```
// save these macros in a header file.
#define fifo_reset(fifo) \
     { (fifo).head = (fifo).tail = (fifo).buffer; }

#define fifo_elements(fifo) \
    (sizeof((fifo).buffer) / sizeof((fifo).buffer[0])

#define fifo_count(fifo) \
    (((fifo).tail >= (fifo).head)) ? ((fifo).tail - (fifo).head) : (((fifo).tail - (fifo).head) + fifo_elements(fifo))

#define fifo_free_space(fifo) \
    (fifo_elements(fifo) - (fifo_count(fifo) + 1))

#define __fifo_advance(fifo, ptr) /* this is "private" */\
    (( ((ptr) + 1) < (fifo).buffer + fifo_elements(fifo))) ? ((ptr) + 1) : (fifo).buffer )

#define fifo_full(fifo) \
    (__fifo_advance(fifo, (fifo).head) == (fifo).tail)

#define fifo_empty(fifo) \
    ((fifo).head == (fifo).tail)

#define fifo_pop(fifo, el)  \
    ( (fifo).head = ((el) = *(fifo).head, __fifo_advance(fifo, (fifo).head)) )

#define fifo_push(fifo, el)  \
    ( (fifo).tail = (*((fifo).tail) = (el), __fifo_advance(fifo, (fifo).tail)) )

// Now, any struct with head, tail, and fixed-length buffer is a fifo.
struct char_fifo_128
{
  char buffer[128];  
  char* head;
  char* tail;
};

struct main_controller_req_t
{
    // all data types are _movable_ using '='
    char any[128];
    int data;
    float more_data;
    char* dupstr;
};

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

struct controller_fifo
{
  main_controller_req_t     buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];   // buffer
  main_controller_req_t*    head;
  main_controller_req_t*    tail;
};

int main()
{
  char c = 0;
  int elements_stored;
  controller_fifo queue;
  main_controller_req_t req;

  fifo_reset(queue);  // MUST call before using fifo

  // always check if space/data is available.
  if (!fifo_full(queue))
  {
      fifo_push(queue, req);
  }
  elements_stored = fifo_count(queue);

  if (!fifo_empty(queue))
  {
      fifo_pop(queue, req);
  }

  fifo_reset(queue);   // fifo reset is NOT thread-safe


  char_fifo_128* buffer = (char_fifo_128*)malloc(sizeof(char_fifo_128));

  fifo_reset(*buffer);

  if (!fifo_full(*buffer))
  {
      // ...
      fifo_push(*buffer, req);
  }
  elements_stored = fifo_count(*fifo);

  if (!fifo_empty(*buffer))
  {
      fifo_pop(*buffer, c);
  }

  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But by all means, please do the increment in another statement before that one. It won't change the generated code, but it makes it easier for non-language-lawyers to read. Here, to read the statement correctly, one must know that the ternary operator guarantees its condition's side effects to be sequenced-before it other operands' value computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael Roy.

Comment: @Steve.  My pleasure, Info added in answer.  @spectras:  the ++ operator has well-defined semantics:  `++i`  increments `i` and returns the incremented value.  `i++` makes a copy of `i`, increments `i`, then returns the value of the copy it made of `i` before increment.  That's why it is recommended to use the form `++i`, since it avoids a copy.

Comment: @dhein Why delete the documentation I made on the subject?  Terrible fifo design is such a common occurence... And it was no more off-topic in C as the 'Linked-list' doc, or 'Permuted Congruential Generator', since the whole example was about using macros. Their use is considered good practice in C, that is not the case in many other languages.  I could not comment on the topic because you deleted it, hence this message here.